# Azure Automation runbook stops for no reason

Tags: azure, automation, azure-sql-database, runbook

I created a runbook to process multiple partitions of my cube. I launched it and 3 hours later, it stops. There is no error message or warning and nothing in the output pane. The only message I have is this one

`Exception
The job was evicted and subsequently reached a Stopped state. The job cannot continue running`

I have absolutely no idea of the reason why it stopped.

Any idea ?

Comment: You've tagged this `[PowerShell]` but the question doesn't mention PowerShell at all .. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Automation runbook can only run for 3 hours.

> In order to share resources among all runbooks in the
>   cloud, Azure Automation will temporarily unload any job after it has
>   been running for three hours. During this time, jobs for
>   PowerShell-based runbooks are stopped and are not be restarted. The
>   job status shows Stopped. This type of runbook is always restarted
>   from the beginning since they don't support checkpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#fair-share

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer ! Have a nice day

Comment: Any idea to exceed that limit ?

Comment: hey, try Hybrid runbook worker. basically create a vm and it will be used as agent to run your runbook. then no limit (i think)